# K-Means, how to access points in a cluster?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Let's say we have a K-means init with 5 clusters.
Cluster 0, Cluster 1, Cluster 2, Cluster 3, and Cluster 4.

We insert 100 points each that should fit into all 5 of these clusters.

If we predict something that lands in Cluster 3. How can we get all the points in Cluster 3? Is there a method to retrieve an array of all the points that landed in Cluster 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***labels_*** attribute holds the corresponding cluster index of each data point ([sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)).
Using this data you can establish your desired linking.

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32232618/5132595) for a possible solution.