# Spark: how to get cluster's points (KMeans)

Tags: python, apache-spark, k-means

I'm trying to retrieve the data points belonging to a specific cluster in Spark. In the following piece of code, the data is made up but I actually obtain the predicted clustered.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
# Example data
flight_routes = np.array([[1,3,2,0],
                          [4,2,1,4],
                          [3,6,2,2],
                          [0,5,2,1]])
flight_routes = sc.parallelize(flight_routes)
model = KMeans.train(rdd=flight_routes, k=500, maxIterations=10)

route_test = np.array([[0,2,3,4]])
test = sc.parallelize(route_test)

prediction = model.predict(test)
cluster_number_predicted = prediction.collect()

print cluster_number_predicted # it returns [100] <-- COOL!!
```

Now, I'd like to have all the data points belonging to the cluster number 100. How do I get those ?
What I want achieve is something like the answer given to this SO question: [Cluster points after Means (Sklearn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32232067/cluster-points-after-kmeans-clustering-scikit-learn)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about `filter`?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit your comment ? Do you mean that I should do something like: ```prediction.filter("CLUSTER = 100").show()```

Comment: Not working, unless you provide me a concrete example

Answer (score 0):

If you both record and prediction (and not willing to switch to Spark ML) you can `zip` RDDs:

```
predictions_and_values = model.predict(test).zip(test)
```

and filter afterwards:

```
predictions_and_values.filter(lambda x: x[1] == 100)
```